# Unable to use IE Browser - Excel Office Add-In - office-addin-dev

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins

I've been uninstalling Microsoft Edge WebView Runtime2 to get the Add-In to load via IE browser. But, I'd like to stop doing the uninstallation and be able to configure the browser engine via the CLI at will.

According to the documentation that should be possible via

https://www.npmjs.com/package/office-addin-dev-settings?activeTab=readme#webview

```
office-addin-dev-settings webview manifest_localhost_ext.xml ie
```

I usually would side-load via this:

```
office-addin-debugging start manifest_localhost_ext.xml desktop
```

I also tried using:

```
office-addin-dev-settings sideload  manifest_localhost_ext.xml desktop
```

But no matter what I get:

[image]

I noted on the docs it says "Office must be running on the Beta channel to switch runtimes". I'm not sure if that means Office-JS or Excel and/or if its still requirement.

I sourced `office-js` as so just to be sure -->

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/beta/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I'm not 100% sure how to check my Office channel. I suspect its not Beta and I can't switch channel likely as its a corporate account. I do not believe there is a channel called "beta" for Office 365 regardless.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/updates/overview-update-channels

There are three primary update channels:

- Current Channel
- Monthly Enterprise Channel
- Semi-Annual Enterprise Channel

**How can I debug my Add-In using IE Browser Engine without uninstalling "Edge WebView 2 Runtime"?**

Comment: Are you familiar with this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/ie-11-testing#switch-to-the-trident-webview

Comment: @RickKirkham that's a good link, its basically got the same information, but more "offical" and details. Sounds like I am SOL because I can't change my MS 365 installed version/channel. I'll continue to fight my battles w/ `Webview2` runtime daily!!! I used to be able to uninstall, now I have to delete the files and even worse, I have to delete the files before I open edge, so often I have to restart computer, bork the dir, then I can move forward. When I want it back, I have "repair" the installation, can't fix via CLI currently as it just says "its installed", but doesn't know its broken.

Comment: Will this feature ever come to the "regular" channel or is it only for `beta`? Would be nice to be able to debug this at work... I'll test at home perhaps where I have more control and confirm. If you want to write-up an answer, thats fine, or I can after I test at home.